# Why jQuery.ajax() is not sending any data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tell me please, there is a form for sending data to the database. Without a script it works fine, but nothing happens with the script. In the console — Form Data has all the data, and the 200th code arrives, but is not added to the database.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;

    if (isset($data['add'])) {
        $posts = R::dispense('posts');      
        $posts->head = $data['head'];
        $posts->desc = $data['desc'];
        R::store($posts);
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="FormID">
    <input type="text" name="head" required />
    <input type="text" name="desc" required />

    <button type="submit" name="add">Добавить</button>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $("#FormID").submit(function(e)
    {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#FormID").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                c = "hello";
                $('#FormStatus').text(c);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of engine is `R`?

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket - you never declare `R` ..

Comment: You have `name="head"` twice in your code snippet, it should be `name="desc"` in the second occurance.

Comment: Imposible to answer with the information given

Comment: Does the form actually have an `action` attribute, or is it posting to the page it's in?  If it doesn't then you need to specify the Url value for the Ajax call, or it will try to post to the default document for the site.

Comment: @treyBake changed.

Comment: @Archer form posting to the page it's in

Comment: You need to specify the page name in the Ajax Url property then, or it won't know where to post it.

Comment: @Archer did ...url: "index.php"..., dont work

Comment: That's most likely the default document, but leave it like that anyway ;)

Comment: @Archer the handler is here - index.php

Comment: I think you've misunderstood.  If the default document is "index.html" and you don't specificy a Url then the Ajax call will go to that page, which is obviously useless.  The default document is *probably* index.php, but I suggest you always supply a Url value in the Ajax call to be sure you know where it's sending the request.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> ```
> if (isset($data['add'])) {
> ```

So the code only does anything if `add` in the data.

> ```
> <button type="submit" name="add">Добавить</button>
> ```

`add` is a submit button. It will be included in the data *when you submit the form*.

> ```
> data: $("#FormID").serialize(),
> ```

You aren't submitting the form. jQuery `serialize` **does not include submit buttons** because they aren't successful controls when you aren't submitting the form.

Use some other mechanism to determine if there is data to process (such as the presence of `head` and `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have forget the `action` for your form
2. Why don't simply use `$data['name']` instead of `R::dispense`?
3. If you what to do a POST request why don't you use `$.post()`?

What you need is these:

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;

    if (isset($data['add'])) {
        if(isset($data['head']) AND !empty($data['head']) AND isset($data['desc']) AND !empty($data['desc'])) {
            $head = htmlspecialchars($data['head']);
            $desc = htmlspecialchars($data['desc']);
            echo "Hello from server";
        }
        else {
            echo "Please fill the form";
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="FormID" action="path_to_php_file.php">
    <input type="text" name="head" required />
    <input type="text" name="desc" required />
    <button type="submit" name="add">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $("#FormID").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this),
            url = form.attr('action');

        var data = {};

        // To have post paramaters like
        // { 'head' : 'Head value', 'desc' : 'Desc value' }
        $.each(form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
            data[field.name] = field.value;
        });

        $.post(url, data, function(Responses) {
            // Will write "Hello from server" in your console
            console.log(Responses);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1) you don't need an action in the form if the form is posting to itself.

Comment: 3) $.post is a shorthand for $.ajax